# How to import a LAR file into a Liferay Docker image?

Tags: docker, liferay

I have been exporting pages from a Liferay installation, generating a LAR file. Rather than importing this file from GUI, I would need to add it to the Liferay configuration in a Docker image, so that I would have the pages already configured when the container starts. I assume there are one or more directories where to unpack the LAR files. Is such an operation feasible, or does Liferay only allow importing through the web interface?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any static deployment for LAR files, as they'd require some context:

- Which site do you want to import the content to?
- Do you want to import the content on every startup?
- Do you want to overwrite existing content or just add the LAR to it?

The only way around that would be to write custom code and utilize the API. This way your custom code can make all of the decisions you'd otherwise need to make on the UI when importing.

Also note that LAR files are specific to a single version (down to the exact update/GA), so this imported LAR file might need frequent updates.

Consider also to look at Site Initializers. But, as before, they can't be deployed unconditionally at startup, but you'd use them to create a new site.